# fetching data using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to redux and I'm trying to fetch some data in my slice file, then put it in my state to use it across my app.
so I read the documentation in redux website. it says:

"Let's start by adding a thunk that will make an AJAX call to retrieve a list of posts. We'll import the client utility from the src/api folder, and use that to make a request to '/fakeApi/posts'."

and the code is:

```
import { createSlice, nanoid, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { client } from '../../api/client'

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  status: 'idle',
  error: null
}

export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk('posts/fetchPosts', async () => {
  const response = await client.get('/fakeApi/posts')
  return response.data
})
```

so now I'm confused. How can I create the client file to use it?
and then, how can I save it in my state to re-use it?
it would be a huge help if you guide me!

Comment: Honestly if you just want to deal with states/global state , then i would love to recommend you to use react context api instead, it's way easier , lighter and less confusing (rather than using 3d party package).
If you like this i can guide you with very clean & high quality code with also TypeScript

Comment: Yeah I know how to use context and I've done a project with it. But now our task is to use redux instead of context and I have to deal with that. And about typescript, I would love to know more about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yeah now i understand what you want, client is just like fetch, i assume they are using axios , then in client.js file they are exporting axios at the end.
An example, client.js file:

```
import axios from "axios";
export const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Then import it whereever you want:

```
import { client } from '../../api/client'
```

But you can also use axios directly without creating any instances .

As i said before you may use fetch instead, or any other http request package, but actually with axios you have more power and you can easily find a lot of documentations

Comment: check my next answer

Comment: which error ?? i don't see anything

Comment: if you want we can do like pair code together sis @SaraJalal

Comment: check my answer. Comment characters were low

Answer (score 0):

You can get your reducer state with the use of useSelector and make sure
you write correct reducer state name instead of counter.

```
const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.value);
```

You can dispatch your action by useDispatch hook and make sure you write correct action name instead of decrement.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(decrement())
```

import of this two hooks

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
```

You can save your api response in posts state like this:

```
export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk('posts/fetchPosts', async () 
 => {
 const response = await client.get('/fakeApi/posts')
 state.posts = response.data
})
```

Full demo example of redux-toolkit: https://github.com/priyen27/redux-toolkit-demo

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my problem. My problem is the "client" part in fetchPosts. Where can I find this to import it? How can I build the client file? Is there any other way to fetch data in redux?

Comment: @SaraJalal Can you check my answer below ?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for these answers. so I used it and now I get this error:

```
XHR failed loading: GET "https://excuser.herokuapp.com/v1/excuse"
```

that's the api link I want.
I used fetch as well and it worked correctly, but I don't know how to store it's data in my state. I used this function:

```
export async function fetchMyAPI() {
    let response = await fetch(`https://excuser.herokuapp.com/v1/excuse`)
    let data = await response.json()
    return data[0].excuse
    }
```

when I use it in my component and at the end I set is to some const it works perfect. but when I use it directly `(like setData(fetchMyAPI()))` it returns a promiss and I can't access data. what should I do? how can I store it in my state?
note that I fetch data in my slice component.

---

my final get api function:

```
const fetchExcuses = createAsyncThunk('excuses/fetchExcuses', async () => { 
    const response = await client.get('excuser.herokuapp.com/v1/excuse')
    let data = await response.json()
    })
```

Comment: Aaaah no , you cannot use it directly inside the setter, because it returns a promise and you should await the results as well, so the best approach is to have `fetchMyAPI` inside some useEffect, let me know if you need some help there

Comment: I got it. so even if I fetch data in slice file, I have to call it in useEffect and set data in my component (for example App.js) and pass it to state. There's no way I can do it in slice file and pass it to state. Is that right?

Comment: I think here is more comfortable than emailing :D 
there's no specific case actually. I used redux recently and I'm trying to work with it with some random APIs. now I just wanna fetch one of these and store it in my state in the slice file. that's it!

Comment: okay no problem , now here is the summary: in order to set some data in state you have to append the final data , therefor you have to await the data whenever you call some api end-point.
Cheers!

Comment: this is my fetch function:
export const fetchExcuses = createAsyncThunk('excuses/fetchExcuses', async () => {
    const response = await client.get('https://excuser.herokuapp.com/v1/excuse')
    let data = await response.json()
  })
now i want to pass data to some value in my state called "excuse". how should I write it's code?

Comment: could you please paste it on some sandbox so that it can be more readable ?

Comment: I added it to the bottom of my answer